# JavaScript: Using the alert keyword and return keyword

Tags: javascript

```js
const lastName = prompt('Write lastName before entering your name');
    const surName = prompt('What is your last name?');
    
    const extraName = lastName;
    const extraValue = surName;
    
    let firstName = 'Stephen';
    
    if (extraName === '' && extraValue === '') {
        alert('Please enter a valid response');
        return;
    }
    
    let person = {
        firstName,
        [extraName]: extraValue
    };
    
    console.log(person);
```

Please I the snippet above but still getting an error of

> app.js:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement.

Is it that I can't use return after an alert?
Please I need help

Comment: You can, if you are inside a function.

Comment: My name is *firstName*. If I use it as my `extraName`, will your application crash? (Tip of the day: `{
  "firstName": "firstName"
}`)

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the same logic using `else`. FYI, you can use `return` only inside a function.

```js
const lastName = prompt('Write lastName before entering your name');
const surName = prompt('What is your last name?');

const extraName = lastName;
const extraValue = surName;

let firstName = 'Stephen';

if (extraName === '' && extraValue === '') {
    alert('Please enter a valid response');
} else {

  let person = {
      firstName,
      [extraName]: extraValue
  };

  console.log(person);
}
```